# Admin Product Catalog Search not working

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, catalogsearch, filterable-attributes

Mangento Version 1.9.2.1

The Product Catalog Search in the Admin Panel does not update the product list no matter what attribute I use for the filter. However the search is working correctly in the front-end. Everything else in the page seems to be ok like the number of results per page updates the product list but for the search, all it does is show the spinner and when the spinner disappears, the product list is still not updated.

Does anyone have any idea or suggestion?

*Update
Same for Manage Customer as well, the search shows the spinner, but the customer list is not updated and I noticed the filter is cleared as well.

Comment: This stuff is fetched via ajax .. for Chrome, open up the developer tools console, click the 'network' tab (filter on XHR) then click on the latest entry

Comment: @Sp4cecat I did that but what should I hope to see? The response is showing all the products.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the host provider did something... after I contacted them about php mail not working (which I discovered later and didn't update in this thread because I thought it wasn't relevant...) I got this reply

"There are too many junkmail sent by your website and it's php sendmail function had been suspended. We just reactivate it and will monitor the activities."

And now everything is working again...  Why will sendmail affect the search results in the admin panel? Maybe theres something else they are not saying but since its working I am not going to pursue it...

Thanks to everyone who viewed this thread, made suggestions and helped add tags.

Comment: your question and answer totally different. please give the answer relevant to question.